# Is there a specific way to import openpyxl in tkinter?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am relatively new to writing code in tkinter, so I apologize for this question. I am writing an application in tkinter, where I want to update the values in Excel based on the entries in widgets.

I have tried installing openpyxl through pip install, and a manual install. I have moved openpyxl to the folder of my project, but has not helped at all.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import messagebox
import os
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import xlwt

from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
import sqlite3
import getpass
import openpyxl
```

I get error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/vik.makker/Desktop/NewProj/Internal Inventory Tracking System.py", line 1, in <module>
    import openpyxl
  File "C:\Users\vik.makker\Desktop\NewProj\openpyxl\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
  File "C:\Users\vik.makker\Desktop\NewProj\openpyxl\workbook\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .workbook import Workbook
  File "C:\Users\vik.makker\Desktop\NewProj\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 8, in <module>
    from openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet import Worksheet
  File "C:\Users\vik.makker\Desktop\NewProj\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 30, in <module>
    from openpyxl.cell import Cell, MergedCell
  File "C:\Users\vik.makker\Desktop\NewProj\openpyxl\cell\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .cell import Cell, WriteOnlyCell, MergedCell
  File "C:\Users\vik.makker\Desktop\NewProj\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 32, in <module>
    from openpyxl.utils.datetime  import (
  File "C:\Users\vik.makker\Desktop\NewProj\openpyxl\utils\datetime.py", line 13, in <module>
    from jdcal import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jdcal'
```

Comment: you should install openpyxl for the python interpreter that will run your code. If everything is setup properly you should not need to move anything manually to your project folder

Comment: How do I ensure that openpyxl is installed for the python interpreter that runs the code? Sorry, very new to tkinter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that although you've installed openpyxl, you haven't installed all of its dependencies (could be just a mistake in how the people that wrote openpyxl specified what packages their tool required). The last line of your error message says that you will also need to install `jdcal`, I suspect your code will work fine after that.

Comment: Thanks! I went in each of the .py files to see where the errors were, and you were right, jdcal (amongst other .py files) was not installed. I installed them all and now the code works!